# Why / is Documentation (Doxygen) removed from msdn?

Tags: tfs-2015, documentation-generation

We are using TFS 2015 on-premise in our sd methodology. Doing this we would like to create our build in TFS, using Visual Studio Build steps. While doing this we would like to insert Documentation (Doxygen) step into the build flow, but every time we included this step, the build failed.

I was trying to get some answers whether we parameterized it faulty or what, so I've dig up the internet. After some research I came to this site:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/build
On this site I can not see Documentation (Doxygen) anymore, although I saw it earlier. The latest update on this page was at 9/7/2016.

Our TFS 2015 is kept up-to-date, but still has the Doxygen step.

My question: was Doxygen Excluded from TFS somehow, or will it be? What other alternatives do we have to create docuentation with TFS Build?

Thanks in advance, 
Collapo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has never been official support from Microsoft for Doxygen?

http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html

Scroll down to:

> Visual studio
>
> If you use Visual Studio .NET have a look at Steve King's set of
>   addins. Greg Engelstad has written a perl script to parse a Visual
>   Studio .NET solution file (.sln) and run doxygen for each separate
>   project contained therein.
>
> Jason Williams has written an Addin for Visual Studio 2005 & 2008
>   which is able to auto-generate doxygen (or DocXml) style comments from
>   most code elements (file, namespace, class, struct, enum, function,
>   etc). It parses C, C++, C# and Java code to produce fully formed
>   doxygen comments, and can update those comments if the code element is
>   changed, and word-wrap the descriptions to keep them tidy. It uses a
>   set of user-editable rules to provide automatic descriptions of
>   elements, parameters and return codes, minimizing the effort involved
>   in generating doc comments.
>
> jgallardo has also written a Addin for Visual Studio that eases
>   browsing the documentation generated by doxygen.
>
> An addin for Visual Studio 2005 called DoxyComment was created by
>   Troels Gram. It is designed to assist you in inserting context
>   sensitive comment blocks into C/C++ source files. DoxyComment also
>   comes with an xslt template that lets you generate documentation like
>   the MSDN library.
>
> If you are using Microsoft's Developer Studio 6.0, an add-in called
>   DoxBar is available that can be used to run doxygen from within
>   Developer Studio and to search through the generated HTML help files.
>   Note: I do not have enough time to maintain DoxBar myself anymore, so
>   I moved DoxBar to sourceforge. Olivier Sannier has introduced a number
>   of improvements to DoxBar. If you too want to join the development
>   team, please register as a user at sourceforge and mail me your user
>   name.
>
> Bernhard Nowara has written a profile editor, which is a
>   doxywizard-like tool for Windows. He also created an enhanced version
>   of DoxBar that includes his editor and some macros for Visual Studio
>   to ease the preparation of the source code for doxygen. These changed
>   have been merged into more recent version of doxygen by Olivier
>   Sannier.
>
> FeinSoftware has released a development tool for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio .NET (Visual C++) called CommentMaker, which creates
>   customizable function header that developers can adjust to most
>   specific documentation requirements. By default it generates doxygen
>   compatible comments.

Comment: here is a link fromt he same page at 17 August 2016 https://web.archive.org/web/20160817135253/https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/build

Comment: I'm assuming whatever addin you've installed for Doxygen needs to be updated (or lost support for it because it got deprecated for some reason)

Comment: Well I was pretty sure that I saw the Documentation (Doxygen) node at the site I linked, but I am not that sure right now. Thanks anyways

Comment: No problem. Let me know if I can help with anything else

Answer (score 0):

Documentation (Doxygen) is an extension provided by 3rd party, it is never officially supported by Microsoft.

And it is a known issue that it does not work properly with TFS2015 On-premise server. Refer to this link for details: [Documentation (Doxygen)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=satishc.vsts-ext-code-doc-with-doxygen).

> **Known Issues**
>
> - We have heard about extension not working properly with TFS 2015    (OnPrem) server.
> - The Documentation hub doesn't loads in Internet    Explorer/Microsoft Edge. (Please use Google Chrome for now)